# Javascript possible to history.go(-3) alert box

Tags: javascript

I know the javascript `history.go` saves the previous 5 URLs in history.

I have an alert box before the users goes back 3 pages (not 1).

I want to display the url in the alert box and ask them if they are sure they want to go back to that page which is 3 steps back in history.

Anyone knows how I could achieve this?

Using PHP : `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` is no option for me since I want to go 3 pages back and not simply 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i get the url form history.go(-2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014725/how-can-i-get-the-url-form-history-go-2)

Comment: According to all docs that I read...at this moment there is no native solution for your case...but I think there is another way to make this work...try to control the pages from the begining using cookies... $.cookie("minus1","page1"), $.cookie("minus2","page2")