# Javascript Browser History

Tags: loops, browser, infinite

I am writing an application that has turned into an infinite loop.  It starts out on Page A, it then redirects to Page B on button press which automatically redirects to Page A again after running some JavaScript behind the scenes.

This turns into an infinite loop.  Is there any way to check the browser history from two pages ago?  If I can do that I can check that URL with the current browser window URL and stop the redirect functionality on the button press of Page A if the two are equal.

Any other ideas would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to custom write something like tracking in a cookie... it appears that you can't get history of a url back 2 steps due to security reasons.
see here:
[how can i get the url from history.go(-2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014725/how-can-i-get-the-url-from-history-go-2)